# How is D flip-flop typically constructed?

Tags: flipflop, cmos

In textbooks and websites, we can find many different ways to build an edge-triggered D flip-flop. Some examples are shown below. My questions are:

1. What are the advantages and disadvantages of these constructions? This is seldom explained in the textbooks.
2. Among all these different constructions, how is D-FF typically built (in FPGA or ASIC)?

Thanks for any comment.

Several ways to build a D-FF:

(1) Master-slave latch (By jjbeard - Own drawing, done in Inkscape 0.43, Public Domain, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=873697)
[image]

(2) (By Nolanjshettle at English Wikipedia, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=40852354)

[image]

(3) (By Nolanjshettle - Own work, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=24742314)
[image]

(4) Using CMOS transmission gates ([D flip flop using transmission gates](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/109027/d-flip-flop-using-transmission-gates))

Comment: I'm pretty sure that last one doesn't have any transmission gates in it.

Comment: #1, the master-slave FF is level sensitive, rather than truly edge triggered. It is sometimes called "pulse triggered".

Answer (score 1):

In common static CMOS technology the D flip-flop is constructed from transmission gates. This design uses the minimum number of transistors and minimum silicon area.